# How to move a point from d3 arc start to end without wrapping?

Tags: animation, d3.js, svg

I am attempting to use d3.js to move a point along an arc from 0 to PI, say, *without* the point moving back along the innerRadius as seen here http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1705868.

I removed innerRadius hoping (unsuccessfully) that would work (http://jsfiddle.net/klin/23c5476v/).  I had also tried setting the innerRadius with the same value as outerRadius.

Fragment I changed (changes marked with //) ...

```
var path = svg.append("svg:path")
    .datum({endAngle: Math.PI}) //
    .attr("d", d3.svg.arc()
//  .innerRadius(h / 4) // Hoping removal would prevent inner transition
    .outerRadius(h / 3)
    .startAngle(0)
);//.endAngle(Math.PI));
```

Entire code ...

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h)
  .append("svg:g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + w / 2 + "," + h / 2 + ")");

var path = svg.append("svg:path")
    .datum({endAngle: Math.PI}) //
    .attr("d", d3.svg.arc()
//  .innerRadius(h / 4) // Hoping removal would prevent inner transition
    .outerRadius(h / 3)
    .startAngle(0)
);//.endAngle(Math.PI));

var circle = svg.append("svg:circle")
    .attr("r", 6.5)
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + -h / 3 + ")");

function transition() {
  circle.transition()
      .duration(5000)
      .attrTween("transform", translateAlong(path.node()))
      .each("end", transition);
}

transition();

// Returns an attrTween for translating along the specified path element.
function translateAlong(path) {
  var l = path.getTotalLength();
  return function(d, i, a) {
    return function(t) {
      var p = path.getPointAtLength(t * l);
      return "translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ")";
    };
  };
}
```

The problem I think is that the arc shape has area, so the path must be closed, while the line shape does not.  Eventually I'd like to be able to separately animate object movement along a series of consecutive arcs similar to the answer to [Interpolating along consecutive paths with D3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19849484/interpolating-along-consecutive-paths-with-d3-js), but first I need to avoid the loop back movement.

Is a simple solution maybe to *not* use d3's arc generator, but instead use another where the end point actually is the terminus of the path?

Comment: As you have realised, d3.arc() creates a solid shape with inner and outer radius. AFAIK there is no way to make it create just one side of the arc.  You will instead need to make a path that uses the arc ('A') path command.

Answer (score 1):

```
Paul is right.
```

You can do next

```js
var arc = d3.svg.arc(); //plus params

$path.attr('d',function(){
  var d = arc();
  return d.split('L')[0]; //will return half of arc without lines
});
```